# React, props inside data-target for Modals

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-props

I have a component that is rendering multiple instances. each element has a button that opens a Modal.

Inside the button please notice the data-target format is "#varName", in this case I'm getting the varName from {'#'+this.props.id}(this is a long string like.. "5a1af3a7c7f04418b44d8c0b") and using the same id for the name of the button just for testing purposes.

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target={'#'+this.props.id}>{this.props.id}</button>




    {/*Modal Start*/}
<div className="modal fade" id={this.props.id} role="dialog">
    <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
          <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 className="modal-title">{this.props.name}</h4>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-body">
          <p>This is a large modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{/* Modal end */}
```

Running the code just as it is will display a blur screen, as if the data-target and the id inside the modal were different but they arent.

when using hard coded data like  data-target="#test" and id="test" the modal works on all the instances but the modal display the information of the first one only.

I'm having a really hard time over this. :(

Comment: can you add the rendered html?

Comment: You are mixing React and Bootstrap/jQuery. You have to make sure stuff are rendered to the DOM correctly in advance before using Bootstrap modal dialogs. You said it works with hardcoded values. This suggest stuff is not in the DOM when needed when using React rendering, e.g.  `id={this.props.id}`